# Where should a Login Modal's state live?

Tags: reactjs

Referring to state of if modal is open or not: If there are multiple buttons throughout the page that can potentially open the same login modal, then where is the sensible place to store its state? If the Header, HomePage and SecondPage all have a Login Button, then the common ancestor for all of them is App.js. I am wary to put state there.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What do you want to store in the state? Is it the entered values in fields? Then you should create a separate component which manages its own state and re-use that wherever you need.

Comment: edited question for clarification. I'm referring to the state boolean determining if modal is open or not

Comment: My first try would be to use `localStorage`. e.g. when form opens up: `localStorage.setItem('loginModalOpen', true)`. Modal open state check with `open={localStorage.getItem('loginModalOpen') === 'true'}` and, of course, when it closes simply `localStorage.removeItem('loginModalOpen')`

Comment: @curiousdev, unfortunately, you can not listen to localStorage and change the login modal view state after when the localStorage state is changed.

Comment: @Emech ah yes you're right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state should reside on the parent component, which is the component that contains the modal(s).  Example, this parent component keeps track of opening and closing the modal component.  I can then pass data to the modal via props.  My modal is simply a functional component because it doesn't need to store state.

```
class EwdsUserRow extends React.PureComponent {   
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
  this.state = {
      modalOpen: false, 
        close: false
     };
     _openModal() { 
     this.setState({modalOpen: true, close: true});
     }  
     _closeModal() {
         this.setState({modalOpen: false, close: true});
     }
     …
     <td>
          <button className="btn btn-md btn-primary" onClick={this._openModal.bind(this)}>Edit</button>        
           {this.state.modalOpen 
            ? <Modal data={this.props.ewdsUser} onUpdate={this.changeData} closeModal={this._closeModal.bind(this)}
               submitUrl={'/ewds_app/ewdsusers/edit'} spin={false} />
           : ''}
        </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/motivation) or [ReactRedux](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start) to store the authentication shared states such as `{ isUserLoggedIn: boolean, isLoginModalOpen: boolean}` and manipulating the state by dispatching actions such as `OPEN_LOGIN_MODAL` or `CLOSE_LOGIN_MODAL` from anywhere in your app.